# Left outer join with scopes in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have these two related ActiveRecord models:

```
class Channel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :channel

  def self.current
    now = Time.now.utc
    where{(starts_at<=now)&(ends_at>=now)}
  end
end
```

I want to get a list of `Channel`s with joining current events. For an individual `Channel` object, I manage to do that by the following code:

```
> channel = Channel.first
> channel.events.current
```

which works perfectly. However I found no way to get a collection of `Channel`s with their current events, without hitting N+1 query problem.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
   channels = Channel.include(:events).all
   channels.events.current
```